# Change width and order of flexbox items for specific breakpoint

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox order to change the order of a set of 3 div blocks on a page.

I have been able to successfully change the order however can't seem to get the 100% width to work and everything still remains on the same line. Any insight would be gratefully appreciated.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
.prev {
    order: 2;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:50%;
  }
  .next {
    order:3;
  width:50%;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  }
  .content {
    order: 1;
    width:100%;
  background:black;
  height:50px;
  }

@media screen and (min-width:1920px) {
  .prev {
  order: 1;
  width:25%;
}
.next {
  order:3;
  width:25%;
}
.content {
  order: 2;
  width:50%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="prev">
    Previous
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    Next
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

when the viewport is 1920 I want the order of div's to go prev,content,next all on one row, when below that breakpoint I would like to change the order to content,prev,next (this is currently functioning) I would also like to have the content div span 100% width forcing the previous,next div's to move below to a new row.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve in detail? I couldn't gather what your issue is from what you have posted.

Comment: when the viewport is 1920 I want the order of div's to go prev,content,next all on one row, when below that breakpoint I would like to change the order to content,prev,next (this is currently functioning) I would also like to have the content div span 100% width forcing the previous,next div's to move below to a new row. I hope that better clarifies for you.

Comment: here is a codepen https://codepen.io/DigitalDesigner/pen/qBXMgdd to see where I am at with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have fixed the issue with changing order on specific breakpoint, to move "next" and "prev" items below, you can do the following (you would probably need to change order depending on breakpoint):

Set `flex-wrap: wrap` property on `.container {` selector

```
.container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Add `width: 100%;` property on `.content {`

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then adjust `.prev {` and `.next {` selectors as needed, or set them to `flex: 1` to be equal width.

```
.prev, .next {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: that did it, I was trying to get order: -1; flex: 1 0 100%; to work but to no avail, this is much simplier and should have considere flex-wrap. thank you very much for the help on this.